# Why didn’t the Ancient One join the fight against Thanos?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, why didn’t the Ancient One join the fight against Thanos?

The Ancient One could remove Thanos’ soul from his body to reason with him, leaving him powerless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 2018 or 2023 Ancient One couldn't join, because she was dead at that time - see the events of *Doctor Strange*.

I'm guessing you are more interested in why they didn't bring the Ancient One from the past to the current timeline. There's a couple of things to consider:

- First, they didn't expect a fight. The plan was to retrieve the Stones, unsnap, and place the Stones back. No fight expected - Thanos coming into the future wasn't supposed to happen. So, no need to fetch back additional fighters;
- I'm not sure you can bring back a while person with the Time GPS, can you? Stones are fine, people... That might be something else;
- would she even have agreed? Pulling her out of the timeline likely messes up the time branches mumbo jumbo, which she's wary about.

But once again, mostly that wasn't the plan. If the plan had been to gather more firepower, they might have well fetched fifteen Hulks and unleashed them on Thanos' face.

Answer (score 7):

Because Ancient One was dead by the time Thanos attacked for the first time and they had restricted supplies for time travel and also Ancient One was too skeptical about this plan too:

> **The Ancient One:** Yes, but you’re leaving out the most important part.
> **In order to return the stones, you have to survive.**
>
> **Bruce Banner:** We
> will. I will. I promise.
>
> **The Ancient One:** I can’t risk this reality on
> a promise. It’s the duty of the Sorcerer Supreme to protect the Time
> Stone.
>
> **Bruce Banner:** Then why the hell did Strange give it away?
>
> **The Ancient One:** What did you say?
>
> **Bruce Banner:** Strange. He gave it away.
> He gave it to Thanos.
>
> **The Ancient One:** Willingly?
>
> **Bruce Banner:** Yes.
>
> **The Ancient One:** Why?
>
> **Bruce Banner:** I have no idea. Maybe he made a
> mistake.
>
> **The Ancient One:** Or I did.

And she doesn't know the future after her death so she can't leave her time unprotected as she mentions in DR. Strange :

> **The Ancient One:** I've spent so many years peering through time, looking at this exact moment. But I can't see past it. I've prevented countless terrible futures and after each one there's always another, and they all lead here but never further.

She needs to train Dr. Strange in the future, so how she can risk not meeting him? We don't know if time stone allows the wielder to time travel or not, and Ant-Man's time travel serum (Pym Particles) was limited.